# Is it possible to send emails from Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to send emails with visualization from Power BI Desktop (not online)?

For example: I created a report in Power BI Desktop and want to send this report to list of recipients (emails) - should be sent as screen/picture.

If not is it possible to send a link to recipients (if I used PBI online for example)?

Comment: No, Power BI is not made for that. But you could create the report in Excel and use VBA to send it via Email as a picture.

Comment: Yes, I know but I need to distribute PBI Report somehow via email, maybe there is some trick to do it

Comment: @Muska they make this a little tricky. You have to pay for the right license & I believe the people you share it with must have a certain license as well. If you get that straight, then you can email your report with several options shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe#:~:text=Subscribe%20to%20report%20pages%20and,or%20have%20it%20run%20now.

Comment: wow, thats great! Ok, i'll find out what's possible in my company